# I would like to place a Visual studio code editor in a Direct X window. Is this feasibly possible?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, directx, slimdx

Is it possible to grab the code editor "control" used within Visual Studio using the VS SDK APIs?
Would I be able to draw this control to other places outside of Visual Studio?

I would like to have C# editing capabilities in the application I am considering developing (with IDE support that the code editor provides).

Comment: I've a feeling that might cause Sir Bill to send some hard boys round to your house for a wee chat...

Comment: The dup link actually provides good information that I am looking for. This should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea:

```
HWND WINAPI FindWindow(
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpClassName,
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpWindowName
);
```

First you get a lpWindowName with Spy++, then by using FindWindow you get a handle of this window and can show / place it where ever you want.

Comment: This would require Visual Studio to be running already, and might take some care to work properly with WPF. Not sure if using the APIs would require VS to run in the background.

Comment: Interesting idea, but having VS running is not at all ideal :(